# post image on a blog with this script

Tags: javascript

I have a webpage in PHP in which there is an image.
Post this image  on a blog with this script.

```
    <div id="x"></div>
```

```
<script>
let div = document.getElementById("x");
let aTag = document.createElement("a");
aTag.href = 'http://www.meteoarachova.com/ws';
aTag.title = 'Εικόνα Κάμερας Μετεωρολογικού Σταθμού Αράχωβας';
aTag.target = '_blank';
aTag.outline = 'none';
let img = document.createElement("img");
img.src = "http://www.meteoarachova.com/webcam/arachova1.jpg";
img.style.width = '100%';
img.style.height = '80%';
aTag.append(img)
div.append(aTag);
console.log(document.getElementsByTagName('a')[0])
</script>
```

But I also want to post a second images at a different point on the same blog.
The two images to be in completely different places on the page and not next to each other.

I put the same code but it does not work.

How can I customize it to work?

Answer (score 0):

Id's are unique to the page, hence you can only have a single div with the id "x".

That is why it probably won't work, or you're appending to the same place on the page.